# Angular $document append not working when start call is from jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I got some code that I got from [this article](http://augustl.com/blog/2013/popups_in_angular/) and it works nicely when called from an **ng-click** directive but doesn't when the initial call comes from jQuery, I'm trying to show the modal popup after a draggable is dropped.

```
var popupTemplate = document.createElement("div");
popupTemplate.setAttribute("ng-include", "'myTemplate.html'");
var popupScope = $rootScope.$new();
popupScope.bucket = bckt;
var popupLinker = $compile(popupTemplate);
var popupElement = popupLinker(popupScope);
$document.find('body').append(popupElement);
```

First scenario where the code is working perfectly, I have a function in a Service that displays the modal popup when the user does **ng-click** on an element inside an **ng-repeat**. This works, just fine. the way I show the pop up is using **$document.find('body').append(popupElement);**

ng-repeat -> ng-click -> function in scope -> call to service -> create pop-up from template and append to body **√**

However when I try to perform the same action from jQuery the append doesn’t happen, I debugged everything to the point where I’m sure that **popupElement**
has the new element to inject and everything is ready by **$document.find('body').append(popupElement);** doesn’t work, the **popupElement** doesn’t get appended to body

jQuery event -> callback to Angular through **angular.element(‘#controller').scope().someFunction()** -> call to Service ->  create pop-up from template and append to body **X**

Do you have any idea on why this later append call could not be working?

Thank in advance for any advice

Comment: Why do you need to use jQuery?

Comment: @JonathanWilson I have the need to use some thing from jQuery UI to enrich my UI, such as Draggable & Droppable, I found the solution to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, I was making DOM modifications but they were not being shown until the DOM was rendered by angular, to kick in the DOM Render I just had to call

```
$rootScope.$apply();
```

That is the reason why when I started the login from jQuery the element was not showing, because there was no natural cycle of angular, therefore the $apply cycle was not kicking in on it's own.